# Is it possible to add trigger and function in asp.net?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

[tables for item and purchase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PJ1Dl.jpg)

I have created two tables and the apps CRUD works. Now, I want to make something that when I add a new purchase record, the associated item's ItemNum will be subtracted directly by the new PurchaseNum. In dbeaver, I have created a trigger and function to make it work, but how do I make it in asp.net? Can I just use pure sql to do it?

Comment: you can create a trigger in SQL server database too. Did you try that?

Comment: Reasons not to use images are [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/92546).

Comment: You could create a function to do what you are looking for in your context file (or other suitable location)